# How to find Odoo directory

Tags: odoo

I installed Odoo V8 on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. I am trying to build new modules for it, but I cannot find the directory. I found it earlier at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp`. I have placed my new module folder in the add-ons. but its not showing on the Odoo GUI, even with Update Module list.

I have only setup the Odoo on Localhost atm.

Comment: try `locate Odoo` to find the location

Answer (score 2):

Please check the permission of the newly created module. Please give proper permission to the module or give 777 rights. Than restart server and try to Update Module list.

If you want to find the addons location of currently running odoo. Please execute below command in your terminal.

```
ps ax| grep odoo
#Here you can see the config file location like, 
#-c /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/conf/odoo_server.conf
#Open above .conf file, in that you can see the addons path of the Odoo.
vi /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/conf/odoo_server.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch the server. For example:

```
./server/openerp-server --addons-path=./addons,./your-module
```

Go to the Odoo interface: <kbd>settings</kbd> -> <kbd>users</kbd>  -> <kbd>admin</kbd> check-mark  the entry **Technical characteristic**.

Comment: While AU is generally "English only" what you **can** do is post it in both languages. First your english version and then your french version. With a bit of luck someone (like me) else can then improve your translation later. See this discussion: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3105/if-a-question-is-written-in-a-non-english-language-with-an-english-translation-p